# Как поместить form в form

Tags: html, теги, html-form

У меня есть форма `<form action="" method="post"></form>`. Как в нее поместить еще один тег form, чтобы было что-то такое: `<form action="" method="post"><form></form></form>`?

Сразу скажу, что вторая форма для загрузки картинок. Возможно ли вообще такое сделать, так как сейчас просто пропадает вторая форма?

Comment: а почему к одной форме нельзя добавить input[type="file"] ?

Comment: потому что использую вывод превью + индикатор загрузки фото

Comment: @Diefair, даже для десятка загрузок файлов, с прогрессбарами, превью и прочими плюшками, можно использовать одну форму или вообще без формы, как таковой. Пытаюсь понять в чем вы видите проблему, но не могу. Вы к этой отдельной форме хотите прикрутить плагин, который по вашему мнению может мешать работе формы в целом или что?

Comment: @Diefair отталкивайтесь от того, что юзер - наш лучший друг. Грузите пикчу в кеш и выводите в превьюхе, обходя сервер. 

А потом уже отправляйте все на сервер одной формой.

Comment: @Deonis, проблема в том, что если я помещаю форму в форму, то внутренняя пропадает. Я вот и спрашиваю, почему так?

Comment: @Виталий RS, я так думал, но что если пользователь выбрал 2 файла, потом один удалил и загрузил еще один. Как тогда быть?

Answer (score 3):

Потому что внутри тега `<form>` не может находится форма, отсюда такие движки как `-webkit` стараются отобразить, даже в корне невалидную разметку, и удаляют уж совсем абсурдные вещи. Именно поэтому вы не видите тег <form> внутри <form>.

Для решения Вашей проблемы подойдёт [FormData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) и AJAX.